# Get a ACF field using get_pages()

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm displaying a list of sibling pages using the below code. As well as retrieving the page title and link. I need to grab a custom field called `excerpt` and output it for each sibling item. How do I do this using `get_pages`? Currently the var_dump I'm using is grabbing the current pages excerpt, which is incorrect.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {

        $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
        $parent = $post->post_parent;
        $our_pages = get_pages('child_of='.$parent.'&exclude='.$post->ID);
        $ex = get_field('excerpt', $our_pages);

        if (!empty($our_pages)):
            foreach ($our_pages as $key => $page_item):
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($page_item->ID)); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php echo $page_item->post_title ; ?>
                    <?php var_dump($ex) ?>
            <?php endforeach;
        endif;

    }
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so I have put in `<?php print_r($page_item); ?>` as suggested and it has returned the following:

[image]

I don't see any of my ACF fields here, so how do I retrieve those? What are my next steps?

Comment: Do one thing `print_r($page_item);` inside `foreach` so we can get that how many fields they get and let me know the output.

Comment: @KaushaMehta Please see updated question, what are the next steps?

Comment: `excerpt` means your custom field or wordpress default?

Comment: @KaushaMehta Its the name of my ACF field and thats the field I'd like to call in.

Comment: Ok, then write `echo get_field('your_field_name', $page_item->ID);` and let me know with code and output.

Comment: @KaushaMehta Nothing is output at all

Comment: @egr103, then you have no meta data saved to that post with a `meta_key` of `excerpt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You full code like below:

```
<?php
global $post;
if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {

    $children = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID);
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $our_pages = get_pages('child_of='.$parent.'&exclude='.$post->ID);
    $ex = get_field('excerpt', $our_pages);

    if (!empty($our_pages)):
        foreach ($our_pages as $key => $page_item):
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($page_item->ID)); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php echo $page_item->post_title ; ?>
                <?php echo get_post_meta( $page_item->ID, 'excerpt', true); ?>
        <?php endforeach;
    endif;

}
```

If you didn't get the data like above then change you custom filed name with any other name and then try.

Comment: @egr103 I updated my answer as per you said not getting with `get_field()`. Please replace above code again then check and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `the_field()`, or `echo get_field()`, *within* your forloop, and should pass the post ID as the second parameter of the function:

```
if (!empty($our_pages)):
    foreach ($our_pages as $key => $page_item):
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($page_item->ID)); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php echo $page_item->post_title ; ?>
            <?php the_field('excerpt', $page_item->ID); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach;
endif;
```

You can read more about how `get_field()` works, [in the documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).

Comment: Sorry this hasn't worked. There are a few things missing in your code but even after adjusting it accordingly it doesn't output anything.

Comment: This **does** work. I only copied the relevant portion of your code, and explained what is wrong. It's up to you to apply it to your use case. If nothing is being displayed, you have no data saved to a custom field with name `excerpt`.

Comment: just wanted to chime in and give a quick update: this does work. It follows the same structure as retrieving a field from another page/post https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-another-post/

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with AFC and get_pages().

Try to access ACF fields by retrieving all posts by page type.

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'numberposts' => -1,  // Accepts -1 for all. Default 5.
);

$pages = get_posts($args);
```

Now ACF `get_field('excerpt');` function will work, because get_pages() doesn't return all needed data.

If you'd like to get specific pages like siblings you could pass theirs id's as get_posts() `'include'` argument (arr).

Read more about `get_posts()` [in documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/).